# How to record from IP camera in Python

Tags: python, django, camera, video-streaming, video-capture

I have an IP camera transmitting an H.264 stream. I would like to store this stream using Python (I need this for a service which I'm writing in Django) into a file on my server. I've tried VLC but I was not able to record the file with sound. 
Any suggestions how this could be done ?

Comment: Sorry, this question needs more details to be answerable: What type of IP camera do you have? How is the H.264 stream transmitted (I assume IPv4, but what's above that in the protocol stack)? How did you configure VLC? `with sound` makes me suspicious - did you get a video with VLC?